# Adding an object to an array contained in a dynamic Array causing Segfault

Tags: c++, arrays

So i'm doing an assignment that involves creating sports teams n stuff, pretty straightforward: Player objects go on Teams, Teams make up a league, entering is all done from main with a parser.

Part of this assignment is using dynamically allocated arrays, so no vectors or lists or anything allowed.

Now, for the past several hours (it is currently 3AM lol) I have been trying to figure out a segmentation fault that results from trying to add a player to a team. Let me show yall the code for everything:

It seems to be happening when a player is passed in either at `team[i].addPlayer(new_player);` in League.cpp or `player[num_players] = p;` in Team.cpp.

Please help, it's been hours and I haven't made any progress :(. It would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: What is `parser.h`? Anyway there is really a lot of code. You should read about this: [mcve]

Comment: If you think you've narrowed down where the error is taking place, try cutting out all the code that isn't directly related to that. Take out all the stuff about parsing user input, just leave enough that you do the relevant creation and insertion and still get a segfault.

Comment: @Jabberwocky    Apologies, I seem to have left that out. `Parser.h` is just the header for the parser my professor provided for the project. I know that that's not causing the issue because I'm not even using it to take in the information about the Players at the moment, just the read function which was already in there (we have to implement the parser functionality)

Comment: @dynothunder either provide "parser.h" and possibly "parser.cpp", along with an example of input that triggers the problem. Or better do as the second comment suggests: change your code so it does not use parser.h and call your Team and other functions with hard codes values that trigger the problem.

Comment: @dynothunder show an example of input that triggers the problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky just updated to include parser.h, Let me see if can make a tl;dr and trim things down here.

Comment: @dynothunder I just played arround with it and was not able to use it. Please add the verbatim output of your terminal: Run the program, enter some commands that make it crash. Copy theoutput from the terminal and paste it as properly formatted text into your question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Added!!

Comment: BTW: instead of using raw arrays you'd better use `std::vector`, that's the usual way this is done in c++.

Comment: Still stuck on this? I knew you would be back, your primary problem was that you kept making copies of things. Even if you fixed the copy cons and operator= you still had multiple *different* copies of the same object in different containers

Answer (score 1):

`Team` only initializes its `num_players` variable in its default constructor, but you use the parametrized constructor to create `Team` objects. When `addPlayer` is called and performs `player[num_players++] = p;`, `num_players` is an invalid value.

You can initialize the value in the parametrized constructor, but I would suggest providing default values for member variables as soon as you declare them like so:

```
class Team {
   private:
      std::string location;
      std::string nickname;

      unsigned int num_players = 0; // Provide a starting value for num_players here
      Player player[MAX_PLAYERS];

   public:
      Team() = default; // Now the default constructor can use default implementation
      Team(const std::string &loc, const std::string &name);
      std::string getNickname() const {return nickname;};
      bool addPlayer(const Player &p);
      void showTeam() const;
      void showPlayers() const;
      bool read();
      friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Team &tm);
};
```

That way, if you have more than one constructor that's supposed to leave a variable at its default value, you don't have to remember to set it to that value in every constructor.

Comment: Oh my god it worked thank you so much. doing num_players = 0; in the header didn't change anything, and setting Team() = default caused an error, but setting it num_players = 0; in the parametrized constructor in the .cpp file worked I can finally make some actual progress on this thing thank you!